# Сохранение активного блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

необходимо что бы на сайте сохранялся выбранный ранее город, то есть активный класс у выбранного элемента. пытался пробовать cookies,  плохо понимаю. ничего не получилось

```
<div class="lacation__wrapper">
  <div class="location">
    <div class="location__active">
      Тюмень
    </div>
    <div class="location__box">
      <div class="location__item location__item--1 active">
        Тюмень
      </div>
      <div class="location__item location__item--2">
        Омск
      </div>
      <div class="location__item location__item--3">
        Сургут
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="location__change">
    выбрать
  </div>
</div>

$('.location__change').click(function() {
  $('.location__box').slideToggle();
})

$('.location__item').click(function() {
  var location = $(this).text();
  $('.location__item').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.location__active').text(location);
  $('.location__box').slideToggle();

  if ($('.location__item--1').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.contatcs__box--1').show();
    $('.cap__contatcs--1').show();
  } else {
    $('.contatcs__box--1').hide();
    $('.cap__contatcs--1').hide();
  }

  if ($('.location__item--2').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.contatcs__box--2').show();
    $('.cap__contatcs--2').show();
  } else {
    $('.contatcs__box--2').hide();
    $('.cap__contatcs--2').hide();
  }

  if ($('.location__item--3').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.contatcs__box--3').show();
    $('.cap__contatcs--3').show();
  } else {
    $('.contatcs__box--3').hide();
    $('.cap__contatcs--3').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Для этого используется [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Допусти вы хотите по клику сохранить данные:

```
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const city = "Moscow";
  localStorage.setItem('city', city); // теперь в localstorage храниться город Москва
})
```

Чтобы взять данные:

```
localStorage.getItem('city'); // Moscow
```

UPD:

```
$('.location__item').click(function() { 
const city = $(this).text(); 
localStorage.setItem('city', city); 
}) 
window.onload = function() { 
var neww = localStorage.getItem('city') 
$('.location__active').text(neww); 
}
```

Comment: Почему то не сохраняется после обновления   $('.location__item').click(function() {
    const city = $(this).text();
    localStorage.setItem('city', city);
   var neww = localStorage.getItem('city')
   $('.location__active').text(neww);
});

Comment: так вы берите данные не в функции:  $('.location__item').click(function() { const city = $(this).text(); localStorage.setItem('city', city);
}) window.onload = function() {  var neww = localStorage.getItem('city') $('.location__active').text(neww); });  }